# Is $e^{\sin(\sin (z))}$ analytic?

Tags: analytic-functions

I have tried searching the internet for any possible solutions to try and find an answer to this question. One idea that I had was to use Hyperbolic functions to try and get the form $z = u + iy$. But the question is:

$$e^{\sin(\sin (z))}$$

I couldn't get past the 'e' part. Not only that, I am having trouble with the hyperbolic substitutions and simplifying them in a way that results in $z = u + iy$. Is there another way to show whether this expression is analytic or not? Or is it possible to prove it through $U_x=V_y$ and $U_y= - V_x$ ?

Do forgive me if it my question is a bit confusing.

Comment: Do you know that $\exp$ and $\sin$ are analytic in $\Bbb C$? Do you know that compositions of analytic functions are analytic again?

Comment: Switching to real and imaginary parts is very unlikely to produce an algebraic expression that strikes you immediately as "holomorphic", because of the general fact that it never does: if $f$ is a nice function, then $f(\Re z)$ is basically never holomorphic. If you want to use Cauchy-Riemann, then you can and seeing the function in terms of real and imaginary parts of $z$ is more or less needed.

Comment: I actually do not know that. I am relatively new in this topic, so I am a bit confused on the relationships of analytic functions. Thank you for the information. (Martin R)

Comment: Can you please explain what 'holomorphic' means? (Gae. S.)

Comment: you can get specific people's attention by typing @ and then their username. Like @haziqaiman

Comment: @haziqaiman Holomorphic (on some domain) means that the complex derivative exists (on said domain). But for the purpose of this post you could think as if I said "(complex-)analytic".

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you so much.

Comment: @Gae.S. I see. I think I understand this better now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Both $e^z$ and $\sin z$ are entire (i.e. analytic everywhere) on $\Bbb C$, so is any order of their combination.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can use this version of Cauchy-Riemann instead:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$